# How exactly are class literals evaluated inside static methods?

Tags: java, jls

From the JLS ([§15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)):

> A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class of the current instance.

This makes sense, but what if there is no 'current instance'?  (i.e. the expression is in a *class method*, aka 'static method')

My intuition tells me to use the same rule, swapping out 'class of the current instance' for something like 'class of the class method'.  However, I cannot find any such rule in the JLS, which in my experience tends to be very explicit.  This makes me uncertain about my intuition.

The alternative is that my assumption that there is no 'current instance' when in a class method, is incorrect.  If so - what are the rules for determining the 'current instance' when in a class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "instance" in this case refers to the instance of the *class* itself, i.e., the class *definition*, and not an *object instance* of that class.  This is difficult to articulate, so let's consider an example:

```
class A {}

class B {
    Class<A> a = A.class;
}
```

Here, the expression `A.class` executes within a class `B`.  However, it is possible that class `B` might be loaded into the runtime more than once using different class loaders.  So, when the documentation says, "as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class of the current instance", I believe it is referring to whichever class loader loaded the copy ("instance") of the `B` class that is currently executing.

**In short, the `Class<A>` instance assigned to `a` will be loaded from the same class loader that loaded `B`.**

In practice, this isn't the sort of thing you're likely to have to have to worry about.  Most Java developers don't have to deal with multiple class loaders in their day-to-day work.

Comment: This makes sense.  Would have been nice if the JLS was less ambiguous about that, though

Comment: Incidentally, I'm interested in this because I'm working on a project that does static analysis of Java code, and I wanted to know when it is safe to assume that two class literals with the same type name will evaluate to the same instance.  Because of classloaders, this may not always be the case.

Answer (score 3):

**Class of the current instance** indicates the instance of *java.lang.Class* whose type is T. Even if the class in consideration has static method, It is always an instance of *java.lang.Class*.

You can get related explanation in Java Documentation for [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application. An enum is a kind of class and an annotation is a kind of interface. Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and number of dimensions. The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class objects.

**Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.**

The following example uses a Class object to print the class name of an object:

```
 void printClassName(Object obj) {
     System.out.println("The class of " + obj +
                        " is " + obj.getClass().getName());
 }
```

It is also possible to get the Class object for a named type (or for void) using a class literal. See Section 15.8.2 of The Java™ Language Specification. For example:

```
System.out.println("The name of class Foo is: "+Foo.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `class` literal can never appear alone, it must always be qualified by either a class name or a primitive type name. `class` should be used when you need to access a class object statically.  `someObject.getClass()` should be used when you need to access an objects class at runtime.

Thus:

```
public class Foo {
  public static String getMyFooClassNameStatic_good() {
    return Foo.class.getName(); // ok
  }

  public static String getBarClassName() {
    // the Bar class will be looked up in the same class loader as 
    // the one that the the Foo CLASS instance was loaded from that 
    // is executing this method.  So if there are multiple versions 
    // of Bar floating around, the one you will get is the one that
    // was loaded from the same class loader as the loaded Foo.  That's
    // what the language about "current instance" in the spec is 
    // getting at.
    return Bar.class.getName(); 
  }

  public static String getMyFooClassNameStatic_bad() {
    return class.getName(); // syntax error - 
    // use one of:
    // Foo.class.getName()
    // (new Foo()).getClass().getName()
    // Class.forName("Foo").getName()
  }

  public static String getIntClassName() {
    return int.class.getName(); // ok
  }
}
```